# How to switch from camera button to video record button in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-camera

I have camera capture button and video recording button on the same container, I want to be able to have camera button when app is launched, then when I a tap Text "Video", the it will switch to video button to record. I have a screenshot of beautyplus app as sample of what I mean
[Camera button navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90STz.png)

```js
return (
                    <View style={styles.action}>
                         <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 20, marginBottom: 15, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this.toggleTorch.bind(this)}>
                                    { this.state.flashon == RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off? (
                                            <Icon
                                                name="md-flash-off"
                                                color="black"
                                                size={30} 
                                            />
                                        ) : (
                                            <Icon
                                                name="md-flash"
                                                color="black"
                                                size={30} 
                                            />
                                        )
                                    }
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture} style={styles.captureBtn} />
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.recordVideo} style={styles.captureVideoBtn}>
                                      {
                                        this.state.recording ?
                                      (<Text>{this.secondsToMMSS(this.state.seconds)}</Text>) :
                                      (null)
                                      }
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>

                                <TouchableOpacity
                                  onPress={this.reverseCamera}
                                  >
                                      <Icon
                                        name="md-reverse-camera"
                                        color="black"
                                        size={30} 
                                      />

                                  </TouchableOpacity>

                          </View>
                    </View>
                  )
                }
              }
          </RNCamera>
         


          
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with condition checking?

```js
constructor() {
   ...
   this.state = {capture:'photo'}; // default to photo
}

captureVideo=()=> {...}
capturePhoto=()=> {...}
captureAudio=()=>{...}

capture() {
  swicth (this.state.capture)
    case 'audio' : captureAudio()
    ...
}


render () {
 

...

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({capture:'video'})}> 
  <Text>Video</Text></TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.startCapture()}><Text>Start</Text> 
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({capture:'photo'})}> 
  <Text>Video</Text></TouchableOpacity>

...
}
```

Comment: Hi @cybercoder please thanks for your answer, am still not clear with your answer trying to implement it with my code...its looking somehow total different from my original code. Please can you make it clearer for me...thanks.